# dump directory data to a file for new/modified comparison later on a linux server

Tags: linux, compare, backup

Is it possible to take some kind of "dump" of a directory on a Linux (Ubuntu) server that I can later use to compare against for new/modified files?

The idea being something like this:

1. Dump directory data (like file hashes)
2. 24 hours later I take another dump and compare against #1 to find new or modified files

Comment: Does the directory contain subdirectories, and do you want a _deep_ comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not the answer you might be looking for but I would use GIT to track down the changes, or may be even `git-annex` if the files are too big for example.

1. Initialize the git repository in the directory you want to track: `git --init`
2. tell git to track all files: `git add .`
3. commit the changes: `git commit -a -m "initial commit"`

after 24 hours make `git diff` to see the changes